# Progress bar in excel, call another macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 macro. One for progress bar, and the other one is the main process.
The main process consist of 4 sub process inside.

What I want to do is the progress bar increase 25% for each process.

I have created the progress bar macro as below:

```
Sub code() ' ' Macro1 Macro ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p 'Sub code()

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)

    UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl * 25 & "% Completed"

    UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 50
    DoEvents

End Sub

Sub code_real()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, pctCompl As Single

    Sheet1.Cells.Clear

    For i = 1 To 4

        For j = 1 To 10000

            Cells(i, 1).Value = j

        Next j

        pctCompl = i

        progress pctCompl

    Next i

End Sub
```

My question is, how can I call main process macro while the macro for progress bar is running? I heard only 1 macro can be run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you don't. You run code_real - that routine then calls progress.
Simple analogy is you can only have one thread of code running, but that thread can transfer its attention from one sub to another if instructed to within the code. So the process flows down code_real until it meets the line

```
 progress pctCompl
```

It then transfers to progress until it reaches End Sub in progress, when it then returns to real_comp at the next line (next i)

If you use F8 in the vb editor you can watch the progress line by line and follow the thread.